# How in Rabbinic view, can a man be killed by grabbing his private parts?

Tags: rodef

> "If two men get into a fight with each other, and the wife of one comes up to save her husband from his antagonist and puts out her hand and seizes him by his genitals, you shall cut off her hand; show no pity." [Deuteronomy.25.11](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.25.11-12?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en)

By the Talmudic Rabbis, this woman is seen as a persecutor (Rodeif), see also Rambam Hilchos Rodeif. But IIRC, to be declared a Roidef one should have a clear ability to kill the victim. The rabbinic explanation of Rodeif toward this woman can only work if she can kill the attacker. But in my experience and understanding of human anatomy, the woman can only hurt the man that much.

How is this woman considered a Rodeif if all we can see is her grabbing the parts with her bare hand?

Comment: How do you know that's all she's going to do?  Maybe she has a knife or gun in her pocket.

Comment: @Heshy begs the question how does grabbing private parts *imply* intent to kill

Comment: Ask a trauma surgeon about whether people can bleed out from having stuff torn off ... and in those days, people died of infected wounds all the time.

Comment: @Shalom This is definitely not a way to kill people, she could grab a knife. Therefore my conclusion is that her intention was to deter the attacker rather than kill him.

Comment: The Rambam there is very clear (halacha 8) that it is something life threatening. You can ask how that could be, but that is how the Rambam understood it. Maybe that would be better asked to a doctor or medical SE site.